# "[...] 以外いなくない?": what is that いなくない?

Tags: grammar, expressions

I'm trying to figure out what is the meaning of "いなくない" in this sentence:

> "あんなすごい事でできるの、シャリオ以外いなくない?"

May be something like this? "With the exception of Chariot (it's a first name), there isn't (in the world) another person who can do such amazing things, don't you think?".

"いなく" should be the negative form of iru, right?
And about that final "ない", I have to see it like a "じゃない"? (As in this case:"この文、おかしいんじゃない?")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

シャリオ以外(には）いなくない? is a feminine colloquial question.

＝シャリオ以外（には）いなくないか？ is a masculine colloquial question.

＝シャリオ以外には、いないのではないですか？is a formal question.

いない＝ヤ行上一段活用の動詞「いる」の未然形である「い」に、打消の助動詞「ない」が付いた形。

（参考）いなくなる＝ヤ行上一段活用の動詞「いる」の未然形である「い」に、打消の助動詞「ない」の連用形「なく」が付き、ナ行子五段活用動詞「なる」が付いた形。*「北陸海岸では、何不自由なく普通に暮していたヒト達が拉致され、ある日突然いなくなる。」*

いなくない＝ヤ行上一段活用の動詞「いる」の未然形である「い」に、打消の助動詞「ない」の連用形「なく」が付き、形容詞の「ない」が付いた形。

The whole sentence is rather rhetoric, using the double negative question, although I don't know whether it's defined as "a rhetorical question" or not. Anyway, it means something like this: ***"No one but Shario is able to do such an awesome task, isn't he?"***

Hope this helps!